# Passing flyway.target and flyway.initVersion property to flywayMigrate gradle task results in cast exception error

Tags: gradle, flyway

Attempting to pass target property to FlywayMigration gradle task

```
gradle flywayMigrate -d -Pflyway.target='1.0.0'
```

or

```
gradle flywayMigrate -d -Pflyway.target=1.0.0
```

or

```
flyway {
url = 'jdbc:h2:file:target/foobar'
user = 'sa'
target = '1'}
```

fails with org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException

```
09:08:25.855 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '1.0.0' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.MigrationVersion'
```

Versions and platforms used:

```
'com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-gradle-plugin:2.2'

gradle -version
Gradle 1.6
Gradle build time: Tuesday 07 May 2013 9:12:14 AM
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.7.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 23.1-b03)
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.3 x86_64
```

It appears that this affects when one attempts to set two properties:

- target
- initVersion

On closer look both methods have overridden setters that accept different types as argument:

```
Sets the version to tag an existing schema with when executing init.
Parameters:
initVersion The version to tag an existing schema with when executing init. (default: 1)
740 
741     public void setInitVersion(MigrationVersion initVersion) {
742         this.initVersion = initVersion;
743     }


Sets the version to tag an existing schema with when executing init.
Parameters:
initVersion The version to tag an existing schema with when executing init. (default: 1)
749 
750     public void setInitVersion(String initVersion) {
751         this.initVersion = new MigrationVersion(initVersion);
752     }
```

However it appears that in the gradle target setting those priorities groovy is not matching correct override type when invoking setter on those two methods:

```
 /**
 * Sets this property on this Flyway instance if a value has been defined.
 * @param flyway The Flyway instance.
 * @param property The property to set.
 */
private void propSet(Flyway flyway, String property) {
    def value = prop(property);
    if (value != null) {
        flyway[property] = value;
    }
}
```

[**Issue 574**](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/574) has been opened with Flyway 
perhaps they can share some more insights on correct usage for setting above mentioned properties.

Comment: Where did you read that target can be set like this?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser [**Flyway documentaiton**](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/) describes passing in parameters as properties as posted above... as well as flyway migration [**Sample Configuration**](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/migrate.html) which produce identical error

Comment: Try without the quotes. In the docs they don't use any.

Comment: Same result with or without quotes.

Comment: Last idea I have is to try with `-D` instead of `-P`. Otherwise, the plugin authors may have to jump in. Which Gradle version and Flyway plugin version are you using?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser swapping `-P` for `-D` switch tip produces same error. Will check Flyway issues list see if there are any clues there..thx for you input...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34989/discussion-between-dbld-and-peter-niederwieser)